# Dual boot CentOS7 / Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, centos

I just got a lenovo T450 with a 500 GiB SSD drive and I would like to install both Ubuntu (rather 16.04 at the time of writing, but probably 18.04 in a near future) and centOS7 on it.

I used to succeed doing multiple boot with win, ubuntu and centOS, but this time I would really like to make a clean install:

- with  all trace of windows removed,
- with both root directories on bare metal (~20 GiB for each)
- and then typically `/var`, `/usr` and `/home` on logical volumes, possibly with a single home for both installs.

I made a first try and installed first centOs and then ubuntu, as described above without trying to mutualize the `home` directories  (and honestly without putting to much thoughts in it) and it kind of worked. <strike>but now, when I boot, after a couple of minutes, the computer freezes on both systems and I have to restart it.</strike> (This wasn't a dual boot issue see comments below)

Yet, I want to do it again to really have 2 clean and reliable installs. I had a look around and everything I've found is with very old versions (aka. without EFI) or with windows.

Could someone give me some hints or point me toward relevant resources so that I can achieve this?

Many thanks,

Bruno

Comment: This might be a hardware (CPU overheating after a couple minutes) or other issue.  If a dual-booted setup isn't going to work, you have problems with the bootloader long before it gets to the desktop.  I'd suggest trying to boot from Ubuntu LiveCD and running Prime95 for a while.  If that works OK, then look through your local HD's logs while booted from the LiveCD.  This is unfortunately a bigger question than can be answered in a Q&A site.

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for your advice, I will investigate further today keeping in mind the fact that the dual boot might not be the source of my problem. And update my post.

Comment: For the record, the following time I've tried to use my newly installed computer, it works without problem on both OS. I cannot reproduce the issue and as Christopher pointed out, it was certainly not a problem with the dual boot.     I will yet update my initial post to try to gather some more tips and resources on the Ubuntu / Centos dual boot on Lenovo issue. I would really like to have a clean and reliable install on my new laptop before starting to work with it.            PS: sorry for the late answer, I was on holiday with my family and strictly forbidden to touch any computer :)